# Set height for popover in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I want to modify the height of popover in landscape mode, but it only work in portrait mode.

I want it's height equal to `screenSize.height * 0.7`, but it doesn't work with my code below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
if let orientation = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "orientation") as? Int {
        let diamondViewController = DiamondViewController()
        diamondViewController.mode = .buyDiamondPopup
        diamondViewController.resetBackgroundColor = {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        }

        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        if orientation == 3 { // LandscapeRight
            diamondViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.6, height:
                screenSize.height * 0.7)
        } else {
            diamondViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width - 60, height:
                min(screenSize.height - 180, CGFloat(5 * 70 + 110) ))
        }
        diamondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        if let popover = diamondViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popover.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
            popover.sourceView = self.view
            popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            popover.delegate = self
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            self.present(diamondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

...

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
 diamondViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.6, height: screenSize.height * 0.7)
```

Try this below

```
 diamondViewController.view = CGRect(x: diamondViewController.view.frame.origin.x ,y: diamondViewController.view.frame.origin.y ,width: screenSize.width * 0.6, height: screenSize.height * 0.7)
```

If it doesn't help then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "Vary for traits" tool? It allows you to apply different constraints depending on the devices orientation. It can be found near the bottom right corner in storyboard next to the different constraint options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set landscape's height in a dispatched thread. Here is my suggestion.

```
if let orientation = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "orientation") as? Int {
    let diamondViewController = DiamondViewController()
    diamondViewController.mode = .buyDiamondPopup
    diamondViewController.resetBackgroundColor = {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    // HERE IS THE CHANGE: CALL FUNC TO GET SIZE
    let size = diamondViewController.myPreferedContentSize(landscape: landscape)
    diamondViewController.preferredContentSize = size
    
    ...
    }
}
```

The `func myPreferedContentSize` is defined in 'diamondViewController' class as following:

```
func myPreferedConentSize(landcape: Bool) -> CGSize
{
   let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
   let retSize: CGSize
   if landscape { // LandscapeRight
        retSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.6, height:
            screenSize.height * 0.7)
    } else {
        retSize = CGSize(width: screenSize.width - 60, height:
            min(screenSize.height - 180, CGFloat(5 * 70 + 110) ))
    }
    return retSize
}
```

In your `diamondViewController` class, override this func and add codes:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    let landscape = size.width > size.height
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        [weak self] in
        guard let this = self else { return }
        
        this.preferredContentSize = this.myPreferedConentSize(
          landscape: landscape)
    }
}
```

It is important to call `func myPreferedConentSize` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` thread. In this async main thread, it will ask your view controller to set preferred content size in either portrait or landscape orientation correctly.